# How to create Linnworks Application (Application Type: Channel Integration) in php?

Tags: php

I have created a Linnworks Application (Channel Integration), after created I have published it. Now when I want to integration this APP then it is displaying error.

```
 {
     "LinnworksPermissions": [
         "GlobalPermissions.Inventory.MyInventoryNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.PurchaseOrder.ViewPurchaseOrderNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.Inventory.Stock.StockReadNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.OrderBook.ViewOrderDetailsNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.OrderBook.OpenOrdersNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.Settings.ApplicationSettingsNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.Settings.ChannelIntegration.ChannelMappingNode",
         "GlobalPermissions.Settings.ChannelIntegration.ChannelDetailsNode"
     ],
     "Modules": [
          {
             "RequiredPermissionId": null,
             "moduleName": null,
             "formattedName": null,
             "icon": null,
             "path": null,
             "type": "ChannelIntegration",
             "group": [],
             "parameters": [
                 {
                     "name": "ChannelName",
                     "value": "TIGERPARROTCHANNEL"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "ChannelFriendlyName",
                    "value": "Tiger Parrot"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "ChannelLogoURL",
                     "value": "http://example.com/testAPI/images/logotp.png"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "AddNewUserEndpoint",
                     "value": "http://example.com/linnworks-api/get_users.php"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "UserConfigEndpoint",
                     "value": "http://example.com/linnworks-api/userConfig.php"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "SaveConfigEndpoint",
                     "value": "http://example.com/linnworks-api/saveUserConfig.php"
                 }
             ],
             "files": null
         }
     ]
 }
```

When I'll go for integration then this code is displaying error. Bellow is the error message:

**Error Message:**
[image: Error Message]

So can anybody help me to do in PHP.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: The Above code is to create Linnworks Channel Integration Application.

Comment: That's a JSON string, not PHP code

Comment: Please che the bellow url: http://webqueuesolution.com/samples/projects/parameswar/linnworks-api/linnworks.html

Comment: Is that the code you are using?

Comment: The above url code is used to response the "AddNewUserEndpoint" module in linnworks.

Comment: Yes this code I'm using to Response the "AddNewUserEndpoint" module call in Linnworks. 
This code is Return the "AuthorizationToken" to Linnworks. If is there any mistake then please rectify me.

Comment: ok. wrap everything in a try catch block. `try { //your code } catch (Exception $e) {var_dump($e); exit; }` and you should be able to see the currently uncaught exception.